# shadcn Input + Form + Zod "A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled"

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, zod

**a little background**

Im using shadcn ui library and Zod to create some simple forms in my Next.js React app.
The input are of type `select` and `text`

**The problem**

I'm following shadcn documentation on how to set up the form with Zod and shadcn's ui components but I get an error when the value of the `text` input is changing:

```
Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen.
```

**Worth mentioning**

The error only occurs when changing the `text`(username) input value.

also, the form is working properly despite the error.

**What I've tried**

Ive looked up the error and I found answers saying to add a `value` or `defaultValue` after the the `{...field}` with a combination of a `useState('')` hook, which solved the error but now it wont let me submit the form.

**Code**

```
'use client'
import {
    Form,
    FormControl,
    FormDescription,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
    FormMessage,
  } from "@/components/ui/form"
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import * as z from "zod"
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select"
import { toast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast"
import Link from "next/link"
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import { ReactNode, useState } from "react"
const FormSchema = z.object({
  email: z
    .string({
      required_error: "Please select an email to display.",
    })
    .email(),
    username: z.string(),
 
})

const ZodForm = () => {

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
  })
  
  function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
    console.log(data);
    
    toast({
      title: "You submitted the following values:",
      description: (
        <pre className="mt-2 w-[340px] rounded-md bg-slate-950 p-4">
          <code className="text-white">{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</code>
        </pre>
      ),
    })
  }


  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-2/3 space-y-6">
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="email"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
              <Select onValueChange={field.onChange} defaultValue={field.value}>
                <FormControl>
                  <SelectTrigger>
                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select a verified email to display" />
                  </SelectTrigger>
                </FormControl>
                <SelectContent>
                  <SelectItem value="m@example.com">m@example.com</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="m@google.com">m@google.com</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="m@support.com">m@support.com</SelectItem>
                </SelectContent>
              </Select>
              <FormDescription>
                You can manage email addresses in your{" "}
                <Link href="/examples/forms">email settings</Link>.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name={'username'}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="shadcn" {...field}  />
              </FormControl>
              <FormDescription>
                This is your public display name.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  )
}

export default ZodForm
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That occurs because you didn't set `defaultValues` to `useForm`.

So, the `defaultValues` is undefined.

then When You use the `<FormField />` You probably write it like this:

```
<FormField
  control={form.control}
  name="username"
  render={({ field }) => (
    <FormItem>
      <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
      <FormControl>
        <Input {...field} />
      </FormControl>
      <FormDescription>This is your public display name.</FormDescription>
      <FormMessage />
    </FormItem>
  )}
/>
```

Notice this line `<Input {...field} />`

The `field` is an object of `ref`, `value`, `onChange`, `onBlur`, and `name`.

The problem is the `value` is initialized by `undefined` then when you write any letter It's changed from undefined to string.

You can easily solve that by setting the default values

```
useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    username: ""
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the problem like you and I resolved the problem by following the few steps:

1. Setting the default values first.

```
const form = useForm({
   //...
   mode: 'onChange',
   defaultValues: initialValue,
});
```

2. Load the data from API.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.data.id) {
      getData(props.data.id).then((data) => {
        form.reset(data);
        setData(data);
      });
    }
  }, [props.data.id, form]);
```

Hope that help.