Whats the best way to set in a client component the default values within react-hook-form?
This example is from shedcn select. In my application, I have the default values stored on the database and need to prefetch it. How should I do this properly? There is the option for prefetching the default values async but this seems not to work in my case.
https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/select#form
"use client"

import Link from "next/link"
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { z } from "zod"

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form"
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select"
import { toast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast"

const FormSchema = z.object({
  email: z
    .string({
      required_error: "Please select an email to display.",
    })
    .email(),
})

export function SelectForm() {
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
  })

  function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
    toast({
      title: "You submitted the following values:",
      description: (
        <pre className="mt-2 w-[340px] rounded-md bg-slate-950 p-4">
          <code className="text-white">{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</code>
        </pre>
      ),
    })
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-2/3 space-y-6">
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="email"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
              <Select onValueChange={field.onChange} defaultValue={field.value}>
                <FormControl>
                  <SelectTrigger>
                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select a verified email to display" />
                  </SelectTrigger>
                </FormControl>
                <SelectContent>
                  <SelectItem value="m@example.com">m@example.com</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="m@google.com">m@google.com</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="m@support.com">m@support.com</SelectItem>
                </SelectContent>
              </Select>
              <FormDescription>
                You can manage email addresses in your{" "}
                <Link href="/examples/forms">email settings</Link>.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  )
}



via defaultValues prop in useForm. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77202565/18079514

as @AhmedAbdelbaset said, pass defaultValues to useForm({ defaultValues: yourDefaultFormValues}) while initializing a form.. if you want to reset to default values in middle of filling a form, u can use reset(defaultValues).. make sure the defaultValues keys and useForm controllers names, identical..
Link for official documentation: https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#defaultValues

@SundaramoorthyAnandh what do you mean by the controllers names? I have used the proposed solution but for the select fields the fetching and form.reset(data) doesn't seem to work.

The solution is quite simple. You can either fetch by using async in defaultValues or fetch in a useEffect and then call form.reset(data). But you need to add value={form.value} to the Select component.
<Select onValueChange={field.onChange} defaultValue={field.value} value={form.value}>


This actually intializes the values correctly but does not store them correctly in the store.
